# How to query related tables based on strict conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core-5, I have these two models.

```
public class Mandate
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int MerchantId { get; set; }
    public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual Merchant Merchant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MandateDetail> MandateDetails { get; set; }
}

public class MandateDetail
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MandateId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Mandate Mandate { get; set; }
}
```

One Mandate has many MandateDetail

```
var mandateQueryable = _context.mandates.AsQueryable().Where(m => m.MerchantId == merchantId);
var mandate = mandateQueryable.ToList();
var pagedMandates = await mandateQueryable.Include(l => l.MandateDetails)
                            .ThenInclude(m => m.Merchant)
                            .ToPagedListAsync();
```

Status field in MandateDetail can be 0, 1 or 2

I want to select a query where Status = 2. And if any row MandateDetail of related Mandate is not equal to 2, it should not select that batch of record of related field.

For instance, from the table below it should not select the entire record where id = 1 in Mandate and MandateId = 1 for MandateDetail because one of the rows for Status in MandateDetail is not equal to 2

Mandate

```
id  |  MerchantId  | Amount
1   |     2        | 200000 
2   |     2        | 150000
```

MandateDetail

```
id  |  MandateId   | Status
1   |     1        | 2
2   |     1        | 2 
3   |     1        | 1
4   |     1        | 2 
5   |     2        | 2
6   |     2        | 2
```

How do I achieve this using **var pagedMandates** or **var mandateQueryable** in my query?

Comment: Your description is confusing. `For instance, from the table below it should select the entire record where id = 1` - I guess you meant **it should not select**?

Comment: @Karan - Yes, you are correct. It was an omission. I'm so sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write query as below. Update your `Where` and add additional condition to check `!m.MandateDetails.Any(md => md.Status != 2)`.

```
var mandateQueryable = _context.mandates
                            .Include(l => l.MandateDetails)
                            .ThenInclude(m => m.Merchant)
                            .Where(m => m.MerchantId == merchantId && !m.MandateDetails.Any(md => md.Status != 2))
                            .ToPagedListAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put where condition of child table too like below:

```
var pagedMandates = await mandateQueryable.Include(l => l.MandateDetails)
                                        .ThenInclude(m => m.Merchant)
                                        .Where(l => l.MandateDetails.Any(x=>x.Status!=2))
                                        .ToPagedListAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry. What I mean is that if any of the record for child table is not having status as 2, it should not select that record and the related field for the parent table

Comment: @midowu I made the changes in query according to your comment. Above query return the record only if child table have all record with status = 2.